# 'module' object does not support item assignment

Tags: python

I am working on a technical analysis project and I keep running into a module error. I tested the code on jupyter but when I moved it into visual studio I got the issues.

I am using the TA technical analysis library.

```
import pandas as pd
from pandas_datareader import data
import statistics as stats
import numpy

def indicator(used, typeOfIndicator, securityData):

#securityData.ta.adjusted = 'Adj Close'

dataAdjClose = securityData['Adj Close']
print(dataAdjClose)

if used != True:
    return False
else:
    if typeOfIndicator == "SMA":
        simpleMovingAverage(20, securityData)
        return False
    if typeOfIndicator == "EMA":
        return False
    elif typeOfIndicator == "APO":
        return False
    elif typeOfIndicator == "MACD":
        return False
    elif typeOfIndicator == "RSI":
        rsi_14 = RSIIndicator(close = dataAdjClose, window = 13)
        #print(rsi_14)
        data["rsi_14"] = rsi_14.rsi()
        rsi14Data = data["rsi_14"]
        return False
```

I am getting the error at data ["rsi_14"] = rsi_14.rsi(). The issue is that I copied this the way that libraries documentation has it.

Comment: As it said, you try to assign a module. `from pandas_datareader import data`

Comment: Did you mean to use `securityData` instead of `data`?